Asyncio Proxy Checking
I am writing a script to determine working proxy servers. Everything runs smoothly with the Synchronous class, however, when I want to do this with asynchronous programming, I get very different results. Effectively nothing else has changed as far as I'm aware.
Async Class:
class FreeProxyList(Proxy):
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    async def setup(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/") as response:
                html = await response.text()
                souped = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
                table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
                headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

                proxies_list = []
                for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
                    columns = row.find_all("td")
                    if columns:
                        proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                        proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

                # Filter proxies
                proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
                # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

                if self.testEach:
                    self.proxies = []
                    tasks = [self.testOne(session, proxy, index, len(proxies_list)) for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list)]
                    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                    self.proxies = [proxy for proxy, result in zip(proxies_list, results) if result]

    async def testOne(self, session, proxy, index, total):
        import time

        start = time.time()
        try:
            print(f"{index + 1} / {total :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
            async with session.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxy=f"http://{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", timeout=5) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    return time.time() - start
                else:
                    return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

Synchronous Class:
class FreeProxyList(Proxy):
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    def setup(self):
        import bs4
        import requests

        html = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
        souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
        table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
        headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

        proxies_list = []
        for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            columns = row.find_all("td")
            if columns:
                proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

        # Filter proxies
        proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
        # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

        if self.testEach:
            self.proxies = []
            for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list):
                print(f"{index + 1} / {len(proxies_list) :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
                if self.testOne(proxy):
                    self.proxies.append(proxy)

    def testOne(self, proxy):
        import requests
        import time

        start = time.time()
        try:
            response = requests.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxies={"https": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", "http": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}"}, timeout=5)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return time.time() - start
            else:
                return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

When running the synchronous program almost all of the IPs work, however, when running the async program none or one work.

Would it have cost you to include the required import statements and the actual code that uses the classes? Am I supposed to know what Proxy is? I don't. See [mre]. What does len(proxies_list) :<5 mean? Is this a new Python feature?

@Booboo We could have, but the imports are pretty standard: asyncio, aiohttp, and requests. The ":<5" is a way to add padding in an f string: example

Thanks for the info on ":<5" within an f-string; I did not know that. But when I see a class named Proxy, which does not appear to be a standard Python class (or at least it's not clear to me from what package/module contains it), then it would be helpful to know if it's from the PyPi repository and if so, which module. Without this knowledge I can't fully understand what class FreeProxyList is.

It's an abstract class that just has class functions which throw NotImplementedErrors, and does not affect the running of any part of this.

I ran your synchronous version and I only found that 2 out of the 48 proxies worked.

You do have a couple of errors in you asynchronous version, which explains your results. You have ...
                souped = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

... when what is needed is:
                souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

Also, method testone is expecting a total arguments, which is not being passed to it, so it will certainly fail.
I might observe that between successive runs of the synchronous version that the total number of proxies being tested and the number that work can vary considerably. In the synchronous and asynchronous versions executed below, the number of proxies being tested were the same for both versions, although the results are slightly different, which does not surprise me (are the same proxies even being tested?)
Here is essentially your code with only minor alterations:
import asyncio

class AsyncFreeProxyList():
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    async def setup(self):
        import bs4
        import aiohttp

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/") as response:
                html = await response.text()
                souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  # Missing bs4.
                table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
                headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

                proxies_list = []
                for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
                    columns = row.find_all("td")
                    if columns:
                        proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                        proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

                # Filter proxies
                proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
                # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

                if self.testEach:
                    self.proxies = []
                    total = len(proxies_list)
                    tasks = (self.testOne(session, proxy, index, total) for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list))
                    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                    self.proxies = [proxy for proxy in results if proxy]

    async def testOne(self, session, proxy, index, total):
        import time

        #start = time.time()
        try:
            print(f"{index + 1} / {total :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
            async with session.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxy=f"http://{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", timeout=5) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    return proxy
                else:
                    return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

#######################################

class FreeProxyList:
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    def setup(self):
        import bs4
        import requests

        html = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
        souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
        table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
        headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

        proxies_list = []
        for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
            columns = row.find_all("td")
            if columns:
                proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

        # Filter proxies
        proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
        # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

        if self.testEach:
            self.proxies = []
            for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list):
                print(f"{index + 1} / {len(proxies_list) :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
                if self.testOne(proxy):
                    self.proxies.append(proxy)

    def testOne(self, proxy):
        import requests

        try:
            response = requests.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxies={"https": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", "http": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}"}, timeout=5)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return True
            else:
                return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    print('synchronous:')
    t = time.monotonic()
    fpl = FreeProxyList(True)
    fpl.setup()
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - t
    for proxy in fpl.proxies:
        print(proxy)
    print('Elapsed time:', elapsed)

    print('\nasynchronous:')
    t = time.monotonic()
    afpl = AsyncFreeProxyList(True)
    asyncio.run(afpl.setup())
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - t
    for proxy in afpl.proxies:
        print(proxy)
    print('Elapsed time:', elapsed)

Prints:
synchronous:
1 / 52    Testing 85.210.84.11:8080
2 / 52    Testing 8.219.97.248:80
3 / 52    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
4 / 52    Testing 3.126.147.182:80
5 / 52    Testing 13.36.104.85:80
6 / 52    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
7 / 52    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
8 / 52    Testing 35.72.118.126:80
9 / 52    Testing 13.208.56.180:80
10 / 52    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
11 / 52    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
12 / 52    Testing 52.196.1.182:80
13 / 52    Testing 13.37.59.99:80
14 / 52    Testing 18.228.149.161:80
15 / 52    Testing 13.38.153.36:80
16 / 52    Testing 37.187.25.85:80
17 / 52    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
18 / 52    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
19 / 52    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
20 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.172:9739
21 / 52    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
22 / 52    Testing 43.131.45.21:8443
23 / 52    Testing 43.134.68.153:3128
24 / 52    Testing 116.105.18.72:10004
25 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.91:8167
26 / 52    Testing 158.160.63.194:8090
27 / 52    Testing 47.89.184.18:3128
28 / 52    Testing 178.48.68.61:18080
29 / 52    Testing 8.213.151.128:3128
30 / 52    Testing 47.243.92.199:3128
31 / 52    Testing 47.91.104.88:3128
32 / 52    Testing 8.213.34.58:3128
33 / 52    Testing 114.130.153.122:58080
34 / 52    Testing 35.220.254.137:8080
35 / 52    Testing 188.166.197.129:3128
36 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.94:8355
37 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.171:10095
38 / 52    Testing 67.43.227.227:11023
39 / 52    Testing 15.204.161.192:18080
40 / 52    Testing 4.159.61.189:8080
41 / 52    Testing 85.210.84.189:8080
42 / 52    Testing 51.222.161.115:80
43 / 52    Testing 62.106.70.185:8118
44 / 52    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
45 / 52    Testing 174.138.167.250:38864
46 / 52    Testing 67.43.236.20:10145
47 / 52    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
48 / 52    Testing 116.107.229.82:5004
49 / 52    Testing 209.121.164.50:31147
50 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
51 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.170:2657
52 / 52    Testing 223.135.156.183:8080
{'IP Address': '160.86.242.23', 'Port': '8080', 'Code': 'JP', 'Country': 'Japan', 'Anonymity': 'elite proxy', 'Google': 'no', 'Https': 'yes', 'Last Checked': '1 min ago'}
{'IP Address': '165.85.253.175', 'Port': '8080', 'Code': 'US', 'Country': 'United States', 'Anonymity': 'anonymous', 'Google': 'no', 'Https': 'yes', 'Last Checked': '1 min ago'}
{'IP Address': '178.48.68.61', 'Port': '18080', 'Code': 'HU', 'Country': 'Hungary', 'Anonymity': 'anonymous', 'Google': 'no', 'Https': 'yes', 'Last Checked': '14 mins ago'}
Elapsed time: 156.14000000013039

asynchronous:
1 / 52    Testing 85.210.84.11:8080
2 / 52    Testing 8.219.97.248:80
3 / 52    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
4 / 52    Testing 3.126.147.182:80
5 / 52    Testing 13.36.104.85:80
6 / 52    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
7 / 52    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
8 / 52    Testing 35.72.118.126:80
9 / 52    Testing 13.208.56.180:80
10 / 52    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
11 / 52    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
12 / 52    Testing 52.196.1.182:80
13 / 52    Testing 13.37.59.99:80
14 / 52    Testing 18.228.149.161:80
15 / 52    Testing 13.38.153.36:80
16 / 52    Testing 37.187.25.85:80
17 / 52    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
18 / 52    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
19 / 52    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
20 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.172:9739
21 / 52    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
22 / 52    Testing 43.131.45.21:8443
23 / 52    Testing 43.134.68.153:3128
24 / 52    Testing 116.105.18.72:10004
25 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.91:8167
26 / 52    Testing 158.160.63.194:8090
27 / 52    Testing 47.89.184.18:3128
28 / 52    Testing 178.48.68.61:18080
29 / 52    Testing 8.213.151.128:3128
30 / 52    Testing 47.243.92.199:3128
31 / 52    Testing 47.91.104.88:3128
32 / 52    Testing 8.213.34.58:3128
33 / 52    Testing 114.130.153.122:58080
34 / 52    Testing 35.220.254.137:8080
35 / 52    Testing 188.166.197.129:3128
36 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.94:8355
37 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.171:10095
38 / 52    Testing 67.43.227.227:11023
39 / 52    Testing 15.204.161.192:18080
40 / 52    Testing 4.159.61.189:8080
41 / 52    Testing 85.210.84.189:8080
42 / 52    Testing 51.222.161.115:80
43 / 52    Testing 62.106.70.185:8118
44 / 52    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
45 / 52    Testing 174.138.167.250:38864
46 / 52    Testing 67.43.236.20:10145
47 / 52    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
48 / 52    Testing 116.107.229.82:5004
49 / 52    Testing 209.121.164.50:31147
50 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
51 / 52    Testing 72.10.160.170:2657
52 / 52    Testing 223.135.156.183:8080
{'IP Address': '178.48.68.61', 'Port': '18080', 'Code': 'HU', 'Country': 'Hungary', 'Anonymity': 'anonymous', 'Google': 'no', 'Https': 'yes', 'Last Checked': '14 mins ago'}
{'IP Address': '8.213.34.58', 'Port': '3128', 'Code': 'SA', 'Country': 'Saudi Arabia', 'Anonymity': 'anonymous', 'Google': 'no', 'Https': 'yes', 'Last Checked': '14 mins ago'}
Elapsed time: 6.2649999998975545

The asynchronous version is much faster by a factor of approximately 25 times and the synchronous version is not returning a different number of working proxies (although there is no guarantee that they should since a proxy that works one moment may not the next or a different set of proxies might be being tested).
Update
I decided to test the synchronous version twice separated by one minute to see whether the working proxies differed in each run. In this trial the proxies returned in each run were distinct from one another:
def get_proxies():
    import bs4
    import requests

    html = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
    souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
    table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
    headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

    proxies = set()
    for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        columns = row.find_all("td")
        if columns:
            proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
            if proxy_info['Https'] == "yes" and test_proxy(proxy_info):
                proxies.add((proxy_info['IP Address'], proxy_info['Port']))
    return proxies

def test_proxy(proxy):
    import requests

    try:
        response = requests.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxies={"https": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", "http": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}"}, timeout=5)
        return response.status_code == 200
    except Exception:
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    proxies1 = get_proxies()
    print('#proxies =', len(proxies1))
    for proxy in sorted(proxies1):
        print(proxy)

    time.sleep(60)

    print()
    proxies2 = get_proxies()
    print('#proxies =', len(proxies2))
    for proxy in sorted(proxies2):
        print(proxy)

    diff = proxies1.symmetric_difference(proxies2)
    print()
    print('#proxies in only one of these sets = ', len(diff))
    for proxy in sorted(diff):
        print(proxy)

Prints:
#proxies = 3
('165.85.253.175', '8080')
('64.92.82.59', '8080')
('85.210.203.188', '8080')

#proxies = 2
('185.240.49.141', '8888')
('185.253.32.26', '8080')

#proxies in only one of these sets =  5
('165.85.253.175', '8080')
('185.240.49.141', '8888')
('185.253.32.26', '8080')
('64.92.82.59', '8080')
('85.210.203.188', '8080')

Update 2
I noticed on the proxy website that the proxy list is updated every 10 minutes. So I modified the code such that both the synchronous and asynchronous versions used the same set of proxies for testing. The synchronous version still returned more successful proxies.
I then decided to upgrade aiohttp to make sure I had the latest and (not so) greatest version. This resulted in an error in module aiodns requiring me to add:
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

No improvement. I then modified the code to force the asynchronous version to test synchronously by using a lock. It ran as slowly as the synchronous version but fared no better.
I then tried with the httpx module from the PyPi repository. No improvement.
I then took a guess that the default user-agent header used by the asyncio libraries might be the cause of the problem. So I used a Google Chrome user agent and that seemed to resolve the issue - but not all the time; the synchronous version generally did a little better that the asynchronous version. Notice in the demo below that both versions returned the same number of successful proxies. But even though they were using the same list of proxies to test, the lists of successful proxies were not identical. Maybe with "free" proxies you get what you pay for. I also have no explanation why when I run this on my desktop the results vary greatly from yours.
Here is the updated code:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

proxies_list = None

class AsyncFreeProxyList():
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    async def setup(self):
        import bs4

        # Reuse proxies list:
        global proxies_list

        headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
            if proxies_list is None:
                print('Creating proxies_list')
                proxies_list = []
                async with session.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/") as response:
                    html = await response.text()
                    souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  # Missing bs4.
                    table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
                    headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

                    for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
                        columns = row.find_all("td")
                        if columns:
                            proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                            proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

                    # Filter proxies
                    proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
                    # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

            if self.testEach:
                total = len(proxies_list)
                tasks = (self.testOne(session, proxy, index, total) for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list))
                results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                self.proxies = set((proxy['IP Address'], proxy['Port']) for proxy in results if proxy)

    async def testOne(self, session, proxy, index, total):
        import time

        try:
            print(f"{index + 1} / {total :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
            async with session.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxy=f"http://{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", timeout=5) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    return proxy
                else:
                    return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

#######################################

class FreeProxyList:
    def __init__(self, testEach=False):
        self.testEach = testEach
        self.proxies = []
        self.session = None

    def setup(self):
        import bs4
        import requests

        global proxies_list

        if proxies_list is None:
            print('Creating proxies_list')
            proxies_list = []
            html = requests.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")
            souped = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")
            table = souped.find_all("table")[0]
            headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all("th")]

            for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
                columns = row.find_all("td")
                if columns:
                    proxy_info = {headers[i]: columns[i].text for i in range(len(headers))}
                    proxies_list.append(proxy_info)

            # Filter proxies
            proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Https'] == "yes", proxies_list))
            # proxies_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['Code'] in ["US", "CA", "GB", "AU", "NZ"], proxies_list))

        if self.testEach:
            self.proxies = set()
            for index, proxy in enumerate(proxies_list):
                print(f"{index + 1} / {len(proxies_list) :<5} Testing {proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}")
                if self.testOne(proxy):
                    self.proxies.add((proxy['IP Address'], proxy['Port']))

    def testOne(self, proxy):
        import requests

        try:
            response = requests.get("https://reedgraff.com", proxies={"https": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}", "http": f"{proxy['IP Address']}:{proxy['Port']}"}, timeout=5)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                return True
            else:
                return None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    print('asynchronous:')
    t = time.monotonic()
    afpl = AsyncFreeProxyList(True)
    asyncio.run(afpl.setup())
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - t
    print('#proxies =', len(afpl.proxies))
    for proxy in sorted(afpl.proxies):
        print(proxy)
    print('Elapsed time:', elapsed)

    print()
    print('synchronous:')
    t = time.monotonic()
    fpl = FreeProxyList(True)
    fpl.setup()
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - t
    print('#proxies =', len(fpl.proxies))
    for proxy in sorted(fpl.proxies):
        print(proxy)
    print('Elapsed time:', elapsed)

    diff = fpl.proxies.symmetric_difference(afpl.proxies)
    print()
    print('#proxies in only one of these sets = ', len(diff))
    for proxy in sorted(diff):
        print(proxy)

Prints:
asynchronous:
Creating proxies_list
1 / 30    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
2 / 30    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
3 / 30    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
4 / 30    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
5 / 30    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
6 / 30    Testing 20.26.97.150:8080
7 / 30    Testing 173.212.200.73:3128
8 / 30    Testing 85.210.203.188:8080
9 / 30    Testing 64.92.82.59:8080
10 / 30    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
11 / 30    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
12 / 30    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
13 / 30    Testing 211.104.20.205:8080
14 / 30    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
15 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
16 / 30    Testing 103.30.43.183:3128
17 / 30    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
18 / 30    Testing 68.178.168.41:80
19 / 30    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
20 / 30    Testing 124.6.155.170:3131
21 / 30    Testing 192.9.190.151:3128
22 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.174:13093
23 / 30    Testing 31.46.175.173:8118
24 / 30    Testing 4.158.55.159:8080
25 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.173:29439
26 / 30    Testing 85.210.84.11:8080
27 / 30    Testing 171.244.60.55:8080
28 / 30    Testing 67.43.227.228:23737
29 / 30    Testing 40.76.69.94:8080
30 / 30    Testing 185.240.49.141:8888
#proxies = 4
('185.240.49.141', '8888')
('20.26.97.150', '8080')
('4.158.55.159', '8080')
('64.92.82.59', '8080')
Elapsed time: 5.938000000081956

synchronous:
1 / 30    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
2 / 30    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
3 / 30    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
4 / 30    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
5 / 30    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
6 / 30    Testing 20.26.97.150:8080
7 / 30    Testing 173.212.200.73:3128
8 / 30    Testing 85.210.203.188:8080
9 / 30    Testing 64.92.82.59:8080
10 / 30    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
11 / 30    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
12 / 30    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
13 / 30    Testing 211.104.20.205:8080
14 / 30    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
15 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
16 / 30    Testing 103.30.43.183:3128
17 / 30    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
18 / 30    Testing 68.178.168.41:80
19 / 30    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
20 / 30    Testing 124.6.155.170:3131
21 / 30    Testing 192.9.190.151:3128
22 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.174:13093
23 / 30    Testing 31.46.175.173:8118
24 / 30    Testing 4.158.55.159:8080
25 / 30    Testing 72.10.160.173:29439
26 / 30    Testing 85.210.84.11:8080
27 / 30    Testing 171.244.60.55:8080
28 / 30    Testing 67.43.227.228:23737
29 / 30    Testing 40.76.69.94:8080
30 / 30    Testing 185.240.49.141:8888
#proxies = 4
('165.85.253.175', '8080')
('20.26.97.150', '8080')
('4.158.55.159', '8080')
('64.92.82.59', '8080')
Elapsed time: 92.5460000000894

#proxies in only one of these sets =  2
('165.85.253.175', '8080')
('185.240.49.141', '8888')

Here is the results of a run where this time the asynchronous version did better:
asynchronous:
Creating proxies_list
1 / 33    Testing 4.158.61.222:8080
2 / 33    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
3 / 33    Testing 147.75.88.36:10003
4 / 33    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
5 / 33    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
6 / 33    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
7 / 33    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
8 / 33    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
9 / 33    Testing 185.240.49.141:8888
10 / 33    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
11 / 33    Testing 85.210.203.188:8080
12 / 33    Testing 64.92.82.59:8080
13 / 33    Testing 31.44.7.32:8080
14 / 33    Testing 20.26.249.29:8080
15 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.174:13093
16 / 33    Testing 103.56.157.223:8080
17 / 33    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
18 / 33    Testing 43.131.45.21:8443
19 / 33    Testing 211.104.20.205:8080
20 / 33    Testing 67.43.228.250:26991
21 / 33    Testing 8.219.97.248:80
22 / 33    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
23 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
24 / 33    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
25 / 33    Testing 68.178.168.41:80
26 / 33    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
27 / 33    Testing 192.9.190.151:3128
28 / 33    Testing 31.46.175.173:8118
29 / 33    Testing 4.158.55.159:8080
30 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.173:29439
31 / 33    Testing 171.244.60.55:8080
32 / 33    Testing 67.43.227.228:23737
33 / 33    Testing 40.76.69.94:8080
#proxies = 5
('147.75.88.36', '10003')
('20.26.249.29', '8080')
('4.158.55.159', '8080')
('4.158.61.222', '8080')
('85.210.203.188', '8080')
Elapsed time: 6.25

synchronous:
1 / 33    Testing 4.158.61.222:8080
2 / 33    Testing 3.122.84.99:80
3 / 33    Testing 147.75.88.36:10003
4 / 33    Testing 43.201.121.81:80
5 / 33    Testing 13.37.73.214:80
6 / 33    Testing 3.123.150.192:80
7 / 33    Testing 43.202.154.212:80
8 / 33    Testing 160.86.242.23:8080
9 / 33    Testing 185.240.49.141:8888
10 / 33    Testing 165.85.253.175:8080
11 / 33    Testing 85.210.203.188:8080
12 / 33    Testing 64.92.82.59:8080
13 / 33    Testing 31.44.7.32:8080
14 / 33    Testing 20.26.249.29:8080
15 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.174:13093
16 / 33    Testing 103.56.157.223:8080
17 / 33    Testing 54.83.185.141:3128
18 / 33    Testing 43.131.45.21:8443
19 / 33    Testing 211.104.20.205:8080
20 / 33    Testing 67.43.228.250:26991
21 / 33    Testing 8.219.97.248:80
22 / 33    Testing 67.43.228.253:12915
23 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.93:13931
24 / 33    Testing 174.138.171.162:36247
25 / 33    Testing 68.178.168.41:80
26 / 33    Testing 157.230.89.122:18084
27 / 33    Testing 192.9.190.151:3128
28 / 33    Testing 31.46.175.173:8118
29 / 33    Testing 4.158.55.159:8080
30 / 33    Testing 72.10.160.173:29439
31 / 33    Testing 171.244.60.55:8080
32 / 33    Testing 67.43.227.228:23737
33 / 33    Testing 40.76.69.94:8080
#proxies = 2
('192.9.190.151', '3128')
('85.210.203.188', '8080')
Elapsed time: 118.36000000010245

#proxies in only one of these sets =  5
('147.75.88.36', '10003')
('192.9.190.151', '3128')
('20.26.249.29', '8080')
('4.158.55.159', '8080')
('4.158.61.222', '8080')


Interesting. I received very different results. When running the synchronous code, I would get ~20 working proxies, and only 2 or 3 when running the async code. This was the root of my interest in this post.

See my Update 2.

Thanks for the testing! These are still very interesting results. These proxies are probably not very reliable, but they still beg the question of why I am getting much better results with the synchronous version, even with the updated code. An interesting problem I think I am going to do more testing myself.
